# Hard time catching Environment Exception in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple code to setup a logfile at specific location:
(Python 2.7.3)

```
import os, errno
try:
    CCustomLogger.setup_daemon_logger('TRexServer', "/var/log/trex/trex_daemon_server.log")
except EnvironmentError, e:
        print "caught some exception...!"
        if e.errno == errno.EACCES: # catching permission denied error
            print "Launching user must have sudo privileges in order to run T-Rex daemon."
        exit(1)
```

However, when I try to run it, I still get the error and can't catch it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trex_daemon_server.py", line 50, in <module>
    handler = logging.FileHandler("/var/log/trex/trex_daemon_server.log")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/trex/trex_daemon_server.log'
```

What's weird here is that even the    `some error` print in not printed.

I Googled a little bit and found out that this may be caused by indentation error ([see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799974/continue-on-except-of-a-try-block-in-python)) but I think this isn't it...

What else could be the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. EnvironmentError is being raised if i try this

Comment: @cyber101 Are you sure the program stop? Maybe exception just logging.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be raising `IOError`, not `EnvironmentError`.

Comment: Based on [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) it should do the work, since IOError and OSError extends EnvironmentError.